# How to solve a system of nonlinear Hamilton-Jacobi PDE's numerically in MATLAB/Maple/other?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab, nonlinear-system, numerical-optimization, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I've been trying recently to solve the following system of Hamilton-Jacobi PDE's, which are of the hyperbolic, first-order type:
$ V_1,_t - 0.5 V_1,_x^2 + V_1,_x(0.1x^2+0.03x+.0.01)+0.02(x-0.5)^2-V_1,_x V_2,_x=0$ 
$ V_2,_t - 0.5 V_2,_x^2 + V_2,_x(0.1x^2+0.03x+.0.01)+0.03(x-0.5)^2-V_1,_x V_2,_x=0 $ 
With terminal time conditions: $V_1(T,x)=0, V_2(T,x)=0$, where T is some final time and x is scalar.
I need to solve it only numerically, get some plots for the two Value Functions and done! The problem is I couldn't solve it in Mathematica, and I'm having trouble with MATLAB as the PDEtoolbox seems to not let me choose a terminal time condition. 
Also I'm not that experienced in solving this kind of problems in any software. However I have available a couple different software so if anyone could give me some help and guidelines in any known software and in order to solve it I would be in debt!
Cheers!

Comment: It is very unlikely that someone is going to write your code for you. If the issue is with programming rather than math, then you should close this and ask a more specific question at [StackOverflow.com/Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) (or possibly [SciComp.StackExchange.com](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com)). Be sure to show the code you've written and point out exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you can just integrate backwards in time, starting at t=T.  Do this by introducing a new variable t'=T-t and then your problem becomes a normal integration with a given starting condition of V1=V2=0, for all x.